# Relativistic change in momentum due to mass loss

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

I'm trying to figure out mass as a function of velocity for a body that is accelerating as a result of mass loss (no external force) in Special Relativity if it starts with $m=M$ when $v=0$.  What I've done is:

$$F=\frac{d(\gamma mv)}{dt} =mv\frac{d\gamma}{dt}+m\gamma\frac{dv}{dt}+v\gamma\frac{dm}{dt}=0$$

$$\frac{1}{m}dm=-\frac{1}{v}dv-\frac{1}{\gamma}d\gamma$$

$$ln(m)=-ln(v)-ln(\gamma)=-ln(v\gamma)$$

$$m=\frac{1}{v\gamma}+C$$

But this goes to infinity when $v=0$, so I don't know how to set the initial condition.  Am I solving this incorrectly?

Comment: (1) the argument of $\ln$ must be dimensionless so you should have something like $\frac{m}{m_0} = \frac{v_0\gamma_0}{v\gamma}$.  (2) for zero initial velocity, the momentum is zero and so $v$ remains zero and you have $\frac{m}{m_0} = \frac{0}{0}$

Comment: right, thanks...the initial condition has to be v > 0, otherwise a change in mass won't change the momentum.